# Append to jquery ui datepicker beforeShowDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two steps in my logic; first show/hide a pre-defined range of dates, then to disable/enable specific days. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to manipulate the existing beforeShowDay property of a [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) without destroying and re-creating it. In my example, the function "disableSpecificDay" is where I'd programmatically disable/enable dates. Any suggestions? All examples I can find assume that the specific days to disable/enable are already known.

```js
var myPicker = $("#myDatePicker");
var excludeDates = ["01/01/2018","04/06/2018","07/05/2018","30/07/2018"];

function disableExcludedDates(date) {
  for (var i = 0; i < excludeDates.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(excludeDates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
      return [false];
    }
  }
  return [true];
}

function weekends(action) {
  if (action === false) { // Hide weekends
    myPicker.focus(function() { $(".ui-datepicker-week-end").hide(); });
    myPicker.blur(function() { $(".ui-datepicker-week-end").hide(); });
  }
  else {  // Show weekends
    myPicker.focus(function() { $(".ui-datepicker-week-end").show(); });
    myPicker.blur(function() { $(".ui-datepicker-week-end").show(); });
  }
}

function disableSpecificDay() {
  var dayNumber = $("#dayNumber").val();
  myPicker.datepicker({
    // Adjust beforeShowDay here? e.g. zero "0" will disable Sundays
  });
}

$(function() {
  myPicker.datepicker( {
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay: disableExcludedDates
  });
});
```

```css
br {
  line-height: 150%;
}

button, input {
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myDatePicker">
<button onclick="weekends(true)">Show Weekends</button>
<button onclick="weekends(false)">Hide Weekends</button>
<br />
<input type="text" id="dayNumber" placeholder="Digit 0-9">
<button onclick="disableSpecificDay()">Hide Specific Day</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a new function; yet I don't know that this is a good idea. For example:

```
function disableSpecificDay() {
  var dayNumber = $("#dayNumber").val();
  myPicker.datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", function(){ });
}
```

I would create a constant variable that could be updated. Your `disableExcludedDates()` can check this and take action as needed.

```js
var myPicker = $("#myDatePicker");
var excludeDates = ["01/01/2018","04/06/2018","07/05/2018","30/07/2018"];
var disableDate = false;

function disableExcludedDates(date) {
  if(disableDate){
    if (new Date(disableDate).toString() == date.toString()){
      return [false];
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < excludeDates.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(excludeDates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
      return [false];
    }
  }
  return [true];
}

function weekends(action) {
  if (action === false) { // Hide weekends
    myPicker.focus(function() { $(".ui-datepicker-week-end").hide(); });
    myPicker.blur(function() { $(".ui-datepicker-week-end").hide(); });
  }
  else {  // Show weekends
    myPicker.focus(function() { $(".ui-datepicker-week-end").show(); });
    myPicker.blur(function() { $(".ui-datepicker-week-end").show(); });
  }
}

function disableSpecificDay() {
  if($("#dayNumber").val() != ""){
    disableDate = $("#dayNumber").val();
  } else {
    disableDate = false;
  }
}

$(function() {
  myPicker.datepicker( {
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay: disableExcludedDates
  });
});
```

```css
br {
  line-height: 150%;
}

button, input {
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myDatePicker">
<button onclick="weekends(true)">Show Weekends</button>
<button onclick="weekends(false)">Hide Weekends</button>
<br />
<input type="text" id="dayNumber" placeholder="Digit 0-9">
<button onclick="disableSpecificDay()">Hide Specific Day</button>
```

Alternatively, you can add this date to your `excludeDates` Array. Something like:

```
function disableSpecificDay() {
  excludeDates.push($("#dayNumber").val());
}
```

Hope that helps.